# how to bind all months to the dropdown list with current month as selected

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have an android application with spinner, spinner having a month and I want set current month as selected and the selected month will not show in the spinner.
how can i achieve please help me.

```
    String[] monthName = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String month1 = monthName[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)];

        String mnth[]={month1,"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"}; 

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mnth);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mn.setAdapter(adapter);
        mn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                monthh=mn.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Short answer: You *cannot* "select" an Item which is not shown in the spinner

Answer (score 0):

Put this after you set the adapter and not in setOnItemSelectedListener()

spinner.setSelection(index);

You will have to get the current date and using it, determine the appropriate index

Comment: this will not make the selection dissapear

Comment: @RafaelT I think he wants the current month to be set as the default selection.

Comment: @Avinash Use month1 to find the index of current month in monthName and then use setSelection(indexOfCurrentMonth)

Comment: it works   LinkedHashSet<String> stringSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mnth));
    String[] filteredArray = stringSet.toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: @Avinash For finding position of current month in array for(int i=0;i<monthName.length;i++) {  if(monthName[i].equals(month1)){
        return i;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

use linked hash set..

```
 LinkedHashSet<String> stringSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mnth));
    String[] filteredArray = stringSet.toArray(new String[0]);
```